# Printing my Username in VS2015 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

So I simply want to print my username from the command line variable %username%. This works no problem in cmd.exe if I just:

```
echo %username%
```

Now I want to do the same in CPP so I can store it in a string or char array. I'm running Visual Studio 2015

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
TCHAR* username = TEXT("USERNAME = %username%");
cout << username;
return 0;
}
```

Everytime I build and run the program (through cmd.exe) I get a random username:

```
013471A0
```

Tried suggestions on Google to no avail. The username is always random. I'm logged into VS2015, does that have an affect on anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this somewhere here at stackoverflow few weeks ago:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <lmcons.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TCHAR UserName[UNLEN + 1];
    DWORD Size = UNLEN + 1;

    GetUserName((TCHAR*)UserName, &Size);
    wcout << UserName;

    int i;
    cin >> i;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

std::cout does not perform environment variable substitution for you.

Moreover, TEXT("...") returns a wchar_t array if Unicode is enabled (which it is). std::cout only knows how to print char strings.

To print unicode strings (those returned by TEXT when unicode's enabled), you should use std::wcout instead.

As for your variable problem, those are called environment variables.
On Windows, you can use the Windows API function GetEnvironmentVariable to get %username% (documentation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683187(VS.85).aspx).

Example usage:

```
#include <Windows.h>

...

const DWORD buf_size = 128;
TCHAR buf[buf_size];
GetEnvironmentVariable ("USERNAME", buf, buf_size);
```